# libGDX change tilemap

Tags: libgdx, tile

I am making an 2d rpg game with box2d. So, I've got a problem. When one of my bodies(the character) collides with another(a door) the map needs to change, should I just create new screens for maps and change them? Or is there a more simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your current map on the same screen only. What you have to do is, Let's say your map variable name is `testMap`. Now let's say your player just collided with a door. Now let's say you will call a method called `changeMap()`. Here is what you will put inside `changeMap()` method. (Assuming you are using tiled maps, you can change logic accordingly here)

```
void changeMap() {
    Gdx.app.postRunnable(() -> { //Post runnable posts the below task in opengl thread
        testMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("someMap.tmx"); //load the new map
        renderer.getMap().dispose(); //dispose the old map
        renderer.setMap(testMap); //set the map in your renderer
    });
}
```