# Java Libgdx how to change map

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have two .tmx maps. For example for now when I click on specific coordinates I want to change map from `first.tmx` to `second.tmx`. How to do that? I was thinking about this answer [libGDX change tilemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599867/libgdx-change-tilemap) but I do not know how to instantiate this renderer object that has setMap method in this answer and how to use it later on because there are no examples that uses this class.

Will somebody help me?

Comment: In the answer that you linked `renderer` is most likely a [TiledMapRenderer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TiledMapRenderer.html) like an [OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/renderers/OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer.html). Since you already have a map, that is drawn you already have this `renderer` instance somewhere in your code (in the part where you draw your map).

Answer (score 0):

You can just initialize your [OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/renderers/OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer.html) with `null` as a map, then set the map later on:

```
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(null);
```

(...)

```
renderer.setMap(activeMap);
renderer.render();
```

Just make sure to not call render() if no map has been set before.